# Calling a function and passing parameters stored in a tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I want a class Foo to store a function pointer, which it got on construction, and to call this function at some point. I looked at these two questions for help:

- [Pass tuple's content as variadic function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105002/pass-tuples-content-as-variadic-function-arguments)
- [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

And, based on the answers, came up with this code:

```
#include <functional>

template < int N, typename... ARGS >
struct apply_func {
   static void applyTuple( std::function<void(ARGS...)>& f,
                          const std::tuple<ARGS...>& t,
                          ARGS... args ) {
    apply_func<N-1>::applyTuple( f, t, std::get<N-1>( t ), args... );
  }
};

template <typename... ARGS>
struct apply_func<0,ARGS...>
{
  static void applyTuple( std::function<void(ARGS...)>& f,
                          const std::tuple<ARGS...>& /* t */,
                          ARGS... args ) {
    f( args... );
  }
};

template < typename... ARGS >
void applyTuple( std::function<void(ARGS...)>& f,
                 std::tuple<ARGS...> const& t ) {
   apply_func<sizeof...(ARGS), ARGS...>::applyTuple( f, t );
}

template<typename... ARGS>
class Foo
{
    std::function<void(ARGS...)> m_f;
    std::tuple<ARGS...> *argument_pack;

    public:
    Foo(std::function<void(ARGS...)> f):m_f(f){}
    void operator()(ARGS... args);
    void run();

};

template<typename... ARGS>
void Foo<ARGS...>::operator()(ARGS... args)
{
    m_f(args...); // this works
}

template<typename... ARGS>
void Foo<ARGS...>::run()
{
    applyTuple<ARGS...>(m_f, *argument_pack); // this doesn't compile
}

void bar(int i, double d){}

int main(void)
{
    Foo<int,double> foo(bar);
    foo(1,1.0); // this works
    foo.run(); // this doesn't compile
}
```

If you compile with ´g++ -std=c++0x´ the next to last line will give this error:

```
    test.cc: In function ‘void applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with ARGS = {int, double}]’:
test.cc:52:9:   instantiated from ‘void Foo<ARGS>::run() [with ARGS = {int, double}]’
test.cc:61:17:   instantiated from here
test.cc:27:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘apply_func<2, int, double>::applyTuple(std::function<void(int, double)>&, const std::tuple<int, double>&)’
test.cc:27:8: note: candidate is:
test.cc:6:19: note: static void apply_func<N, ARGS>::applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, ARGS ...) [with int N = 2, ARGS = {int, double}]
test.cc:6:19: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
test.cc: In static member function ‘static void apply_func<N, ARGS>::applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, ARGS ...) [with int N = 2, ARGS = {int, double}]’:
test.cc:27:8:   instantiated from ‘void applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with ARGS = {int, double}]’
test.cc:52:9:   instantiated from ‘void Foo<ARGS>::run() [with ARGS = {int, double}]’
test.cc:61:17:   instantiated from here
test.cc:9:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘apply_func<1>::applyTuple(std::function<void(int, double)>&, const std::tuple<int, double>&, const double&, int&, double&)’
test.cc:9:9: note: candidate is:
test.cc:6:19: note: static void apply_func<N, ARGS>::applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, ARGS ...) [with int N = 1, ARGS = {}]
test.cc:6:19: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 5 provided
test.cc: In static member function ‘static void apply_func<N, ARGS>::applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, ARGS ...) [with int N = 1, ARGS = {}]’:
test.cc:9:9:   instantiated from ‘static void apply_func<N, ARGS>::applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, ARGS ...) [with int N = 2, ARGS = {int, double}]’
test.cc:27:8:   instantiated from ‘void applyTuple(std::function<void(ARGS ...)>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with ARGS = {int, double}]’
test.cc:52:9:   instantiated from ‘void Foo<ARGS>::run() [with ARGS = {int, double}]’
test.cc:61:17:   instantiated from here
test.cc:9:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(const std::tuple<>&)’
test.cc:9:9: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/utility:133:5: note: template<long unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/utility:138:5: note: template<long unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> const typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(const std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:531:5: note: template<long unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> typename std::__add_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:538:5: note: template<long unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> typename std::__add_c_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was the combination of three errors:

1. the pointer error pointed out by user:templatetypedef
2. I had to go back to the original version of apply tuple in this post: [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments). I changed all the template parameters to `ARGS...` because for the tuple, function and class they are all the same. Honestly, I still don't understand why that shouldn't work...
3. The function pointer had to be stored as such (`void (*m_f) (ARGS...);`) instead of a `std::function<void(ARGS...)>` object as I did. The constructor had to be changed accordingly, of course

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `applyTuple` takes a reference to a tuple as its second parameter:

```
template < typename... ARGS >
void applyTuple( std::function<void(ARGS...)>& f,
                 std::tuple<ARGS...> const& t ) {
   apply_func<sizeof...(ARGS), ARGS...>::applyTuple( f, t );
}
```

But, inside of `run`, you're passing in a pointer to a tuple, since `argument_pack` is a pointer to a tuple:

```
std::tuple<ARGS...> *argument_pack;
```

If you change the body of `run` to be

```
applyTuple<ARGS...>(m_f, *argument_pack);
```

then I think your problem should go away.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, this is embarrassing... I am throwing around variadic templates and I am not able to dereference a pointer where I need to! Anyways, it is still not compiling. Thank you for pointing the error out! I updated the question.

Comment: as long as when you omit a small detail you get a nice clear and concise error message from the compiler telling you what you've done rather than some convoluted template mess to work through.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say `apply_func<N-1>::...`. This will instantiate the structure with `ARGS = {}`, thus the "candidate expects 2 arguments, 5 provided" error.

Also, in `applyTuple`, you have used `apply_func<sizeof...(ARGS), ARGS...>::applyTuple`, which expects to accept 4 parameters: the function `f`, the tuple `t`, and the `ARGS... args`, but you cannot pass the *args*, thus the "candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided" error.

As an alternate solution, you could use my [vtmp](https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/vtmp.hpp) library and use

```
template<typename... ARGS>
void Foo<ARGS...>::run()
{
    utils::tuple_apply(*argument_pack, m_f);
}
```

(Note: requires g++ 4.7)