# Variadic variable initialization for variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a templated class A in which I want to call a templated function from another class B

the header looks like :

```
template<typename... T> class A
{
public:
    A();
    void get(type_X params);
private:
    B b_;
};
```

and the .hxx :

```
template<typename... T> void A<T...>::get(type_X params)
{
    /*here lies my problem*/
    T... variable; // just like we would do string s;
                   // and pass it to a function f(string& s) to assign it
    b_.get(params, variable...);
    /* do something with updated value of variable */
}
```

where member b_ (class B) has a templated function get which looks like

```
template<typename... T> int B<T...>::get(type_X params, const T&... variable)
{
    /* change variable, just like we would assign a new value to a string& */
    return 0; 
}
```

And I have no idea how to initialize (if possible) my "T..." object to be given as argument to templated function B::get.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the indices machinery to create a pack of integral indices at compile time:

```
template< std::size_t... Ns >
struct indices {
    typedef indices< Ns..., sizeof...( Ns ) > next;
};

template< std::size_t N >
struct make_indices {
    typedef typename make_indices< N - 1 >::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct make_indices< 0 > {
    typedef indices<> type;
};
```

Now, you can create an array of objects:

```
T vars[] = { T()... };
```

Next, you need a helper function to create a context where you can deduce the pack of integers. Something like this:

```
template<typename... T, T, size_t... I>
int helper(type_X params, T* arr, indices<I...>)
{
    return b_.get(params, arr[I]...);
}
```

For `arr` parameter you'd pass the array `vars` you created previously and for the last one you pass `make_indices<sizeof...(T)>::type()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I need to retrieve the modified object variable, this was not clear in my post I am going to edit it.

Comment: Your answer made my code compile, but if I understand correctly this does not allow me to retrieve an updated T... object I could use in A::get scope ?

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly. Hope that suits your needs.

Comment: Why do I need to create an array container with (in my case) only one element ? Your previous temporary T()... syntax cannot work to initialize the unique object I need ?

Comment: Unless the size of this array represents the number of element in my T... object ?

Comment: Yes, the size of the array will be deduced by the size of `T...` pack. If there's only one element, the array's size will be 1.

Comment: I can't use std::initializer_list<T> as I have different types (int, int, std::string, std::string) as T...

Comment: Your method works fine, it looks a lot like what a coworker does when dealing with templating methods inspirated by functional programation, but I realize my design is not right as it won't allow me to do what I intended to :(

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is invalid syntax:

```
T... variable;
```

To do something like this, you need to create a tuple:

```
std::tuple<T...> variable;
```

And then you use one of the techniques to call a function with the tuple members as parameters:

["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer)
[Pass tuple's content as variadic function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105002/pass-tuples-content-as-variadic-function-arguments)
[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

Comment: Yes I know this is invalid, I wanted to do something similar. But I don't even know if this exists.
Tuple seem to work, but as I told jrok my design was not correct, but thanks anyway this is a solution to the problem I exposed.

Comment: Using your tuple<T...> allows me to solve my problem _theoricaly_ : `sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand ‘T ...’ into a fixed-length argument list` :) I need a new compiler ..

Comment: Yes, you do. Or a newer standard library at least, because tuple's argument list shouldn't be fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you:

```
#if 1 // Not in C++11
// Helper class to be able to use expansion of std::get<Index>(tuple)
template <int... Is> struct index_sequence {};

// Following create index_sequence<0, 1, 2, .., sizeof...(Is) - 1>
template <int Index, int... Is>
struct make_index_sequence { // recursively build a sequence of indices
    typedef typename make_index_sequence<Index - 1, Index -1, Is...>::type type;
};

template <int... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> { // stop the recursion when 0 is reached
    typedef index_sequence<Is...> type;
};
#endif

template<typename... Ts> class A
{
public:
    void get(type_X params)
    {
        std::tuple<Ts...> t;
        a.get(params, t, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
    }
private:
    template<std::size_t ... Is>
    void get(type_X params, std::tuple<Ts...>& t, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        b_.get(params, std::get<Is>(t)...);
    }

private:
    B b_;
};
```